# how can I use nested css template literals in styled-components, emotion

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

```
const someStyle = css`
  colors : ${({theme}) => theme.colors.primary; 
  ${(props) => props.active ? css`
   background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.backgroundColorActive};
  `}
`

const SomeButton = styled.div`
  ${someStyle} 
`
```

Can I use `css` template literals  nested in another css template literals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even easier you can just use a simple Template strings:

```css
const someStyle = `
  color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.primary; 
  ${(props) => props.active ? `
   background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.backgroundColorActive};
  `}
`

const SomeButton = styled.div`
  ${someStyle} 
`
```

Comment: really appreciate your answer.  One thing I should know is how to use template strings with nested css.

Comment: @jay1234 It's the same just with `css` before (like you do). But be aware that `colors:` isn't valid but `color:` is ;)